# Swift Unit Test if method can handle optional set to nil

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, swift, tdd, xctest

This applies to a project with both ObjC and Swift, where the code I relate to is written and tested in Swift.

I have a communicator class which receives a document object and from that object should retrieve a documentId. My communicator has a serverPathForDocument: method, which uses this documentId to build a remote path to fetch relevant data.

Writing unit tests for the communicator I realised I wanted to know if my serverPathForDocument: method can handle a non-initiated (nil) value on the documentId. If written in Obj-C my test would look something like:

```
- (void)testThatRemotePathForDocumentCanHandleNilDocumentId {
   testDocument.documentId = nil
   XCTAssertNoThrow([sut serverPathForDocument: testDocument], "Method should handle nil argument");
}
```

Swift doesn't have exception, or so I've read, so how would I write a proper unit test that checks if a method can handle an optional set to nil?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably want the `serverPathForDocument` method to return an optional path object (whatever it means for you). It would then be the responsibility of the caller to make sure the optional isn't `nil` and really represents a path.